# Read Cell Value then logical test If, Else if and execute function based on cell value Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Google Sheets - Google Apps Script

I'm trying to make an IF ELSEIF logical test but having no luck, it just didn't work

I've something like this :

```
  var employee = 
  {
    data1: rec[1],
    data2: rec[2]
  };

return employee;
}

function handleEmployeeOld(row, employee)
{
  var templ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('employeeold-details');
  });
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 15).setValue('Old-Done');
}

function handleEmployeeNew(row, employee)
{
  var templ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('employeenew-details');
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 15).setValue('New-Done');
}
```

I want to check if "data2" contain "old" it will execute function handleEmployeeOld, and if "data2" contain "new" it will execute function handleEmployeeNew, I think it will be easier/effective if making new function for check the data2 value/text

Comment: What does "_having no luck, it just didn't work_" mean, in this case?

Comment: I don't see any [`if/else` statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) in your code.

Comment: Ohh, i'm sorry, i forgot to copy the if function, but @Cooper answer's already works well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(employee.data2.includes("old") {
  //do something
} else {
  //do something else
}
```